# IE7 float right problems

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Html=>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div style='border: 1px solid red; width: 100px;'>
    <a href="#">foo</a>
    <a href="#"style="border-color: blue; float: right;">bar</a>                
  </div>
something
</body>
</html>
```

I got problems with IE7 (IE6 support is not needed)

On IE7 rendered html looks like this=>
[image]

I need it to look like this (works on chrome/ie8 at the moment)=>
[image]

What should i change? :)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You need to float both elements and clear it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100px;">
    <a href="#" style="border-color: blue; float: right;">bar</a>    
    <a href="#" style="float:left;">foo</a>            
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
something
</body>
</html>
```

Or simply put the floating element in front of the normal element like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100px;">
    <a href="#" style="border-color: blue; float: right;">bar</a>    
    <a href="#">foo</a>            
  </div>
something
</body>
</html>
```

#### Brief Explanation:

Pardon my english and drawing, but here's briefly how float and clearing works in cross browser:

An element can be floated left or right. When you have element floating, the element doesn't push "normal" content downwards. See why -

Float and clear:

[image]
*Legend: Orange/Float Right, Blue/Float Left, Gray Lines/Clear divider, Red Rect/bounds*

In this case, you have 2 elements of one line text - one float left, and the other float right. When floating, it will not push the contents downwards aka taking space. Thus if you do not use `clear:both` at the gray lines, the contents below will stack upwards between the 2 floating elements and thus may not be what you want.

When you use `clear:both` below the floats, the content below the floats will be pushed as far as whichever float element is of highest height. This is shown in the diagram's 2nd and 3rd section.

Float only:

[image]
*Legend: Orange/Float Right, Blue/Normal content, Gray Lines/the line that is divded with the next, Red Rect/bounds*

The blue normal content is already by default `text-align: left;`. Thus it is left oriented. You need the float to be in front of the normal content because you're telling the browser to float from this line.

You should experiment different conditions to see its effect: putting float in front, behind, float left right, clear both, clear right and left.

Comment: Thanks. Got it working (2nd approach). Any deeper explanation why this is so?

Comment: I'll try explaining but pardon my english =)

Comment: IE6 and 7 both do this, and it's caused by their stunningly creaky layout engine - it was never built with CSS in mind and it still shows, even in IE8. The 2nd option here (put the float:right element first) is probably the most commonly seen.

Answer (score 1):

Always helpfull for all IE-Float-Combos: Give every float-element a `display: inline;`

Comment: `display:inline;` for `bar` link somehow did not help. Maybe i understood you wrong.

Comment: display:inline for the float-element will (in many cases) solve common float problems with IE's wrong calculated padding and margin values.

Answer (score 0):

Try the clear after fix:

```
div:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Tried this with no success. Maybe did something wrong. Anyway - got it working.