# Problems with IE7 keeping two buttons in a same line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with IE7.

I'm trying to put 2 buttons in the same line.. but its not working only for IE7 in all other browsers it works as it should( didn't check IE6, will no check). Here is a picture so you know what I mean 
 [image]

This black border you see is just something I put so I can see how long/tall is my div. Which css style should buttons have in order to be in the same line. Thank you

**UPDATE-> HERE IS SOME HTML :**

```
<div style="border:1px solid; width:300px; height:30px; float:left; padding:0;margin:0;text-align:left;">
                    <a class="button niceButton"> 
                        <div id="first" class="action_button">
                            EDIT CATEGORY
                        </div>  
                    </a>
                    <a class="button niceButton"> 
                        <div id="action_delete" class="action_button1">
                            DELETE RECORDS
                        </div>  
                    </a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: See a full explanation at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820007/ie7-float-right-problems/1820018#1820018

Comment: @thephpdeveloper, tried that also not working with clear both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left one should have `float: left;` and the right one should have `float: right;` and it's recommended to place a `clear: both;` on the element after the `div` with the `button`s.

Example:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="left">left button</button>
    <button class="right">right button</button>
</div>
```

with

```
.buttons {
    width: 300px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Still not happening I used your style for buttons. I updated the question

Comment: Your code is wrong. You should float the buttons, not the div.

Comment: Yes I figured that out, its not actually my code I'm just fixing it , I got rid of div elements used just a, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried display: inline; on the buttons?

Edit:

also shouldnt the  be inside the div around the text like so:

```
<div id="first" class="action_button">
<a class="button niceButton">EDIT CATEGORY</a>
</div>
```