# Even sized input boxes that line up with each other, not the start of the text

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code that is inside the body tag and with the css styles applied. I want to have the text boxes all line up with each other so it looks nice and even. However, I was only able to get them to be even sized so that the heading is above them, whereas I'd like them inlined. Something like (Excuse my paint skills, also I forgot to make the box lines thin that isn't something I want it to look like):

[image: Example image]

```css
.FormContainer {
  width: 500px;
  clear: both;
}
.FormContainer input {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="FormContainer">
  <form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="EmailAddressLoginField">Email Address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="EmailAddressLoginField" id="EmailAddressLoginField">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="PasswordLoginField">Password:</label>
      <input type="text" name="PasswordLoginField" id="PasswordLoginField">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="LoginButton" id="LoginButton" value="Login">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Without any css styling it will look like this, which is what I don't want:

[image: Example bad output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible way will be to make use of a **CSS table**. Over the other solutions provided, this does not ask you to define a width for the `label` (which you might not know beforehand in a dynamic world).

```css
.FormContainer {
  width: 500px;
  clear: both;
}
.FormContainer input {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
.FormContainer form {
  display: table;
}
.FormContainer form p {
  display: table-row;
}
.FormContainer form p label,
.FormContainer form p input[type=text] {
  display: table-cell;
}
/* if the last paragraph in a form
always contains the submit button, add this: */

.FormContainer form p:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="FormContainer">
  <form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="EmailAddressLoginField">Email Address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="EmailAddressLoginField" id="EmailAddressLoginField">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="PasswordLoginField">Password:</label>
      <input type="text" name="PasswordLoginField" id="PasswordLoginField">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="LoginButton" id="LoginButton" value="Login">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a bit more space between the text and input box?

Comment: Add `.FormContainer form p label { padding-right: 10px; }`  or whatever suits you.

Comment: Not sure if it is outside the scope of this question, but how can I vertically align the text to the centre of the input box. At the moment it is on the bottom. I tried `.FormContainer form p label { vertical-align: middle; }` but that seemed to affect the input box as well

Comment: Please ask a new question and provide a snippet that clearly demonstrates the problem. As of now the snippet in my answer seems just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the third option I originally provided - you set a fixed width for the label (and the same value for the `<p>` "padding-left" property: https://jsfiddle.net/p8zmhhwr/2/

```css
.FormContainer {
  width: 500px;
}
.FormContainer p {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 120px;
}
.FormContainer p:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.FormContainer input,
.FormContainer label {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.FormContainer input {
  width: 100%;
}
.FormContainer label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="FormContainer">
  <form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="EmailAddressLoginField">Email Address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="EmailAddressLoginField" id="EmailAddressLoginField">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="PasswordLoginField">Password:</label>
      <input type="text" name="PasswordLoginField" id="PasswordLoginField">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="LoginButton" id="LoginButton" value="Login">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

The original 50/50% solution: https://jsfiddle.net/p8zmhhwr/, and the revised 70/30% solution: https://jsfiddle.net/p8zmhhwr/1/

Comment: This is a clearly inferior solution as this requires you to define a width for the label. Check what happens if you use a long label like *ZIP-Code (only if located in US)*. It is more complex regarding the code it requires and completely inflexible.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what technique you're wanting to use...
Here's what I whipped up:

```css
.FormContainer {
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}
.FormContainer label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 120px;
}
.FormContainer input:not([type="submit"]){
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="FormContainer">
  <form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="EmailAddressLoginField">Email Address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="EmailAddressLoginField" id="EmailAddressLoginField">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="PasswordLoginField">Password:</label>
      <input type="text" name="PasswordLoginField" id="PasswordLoginField">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="LoginButton" id="LoginButton" value="Login">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

a table would be one possibility...

```
<div class="FormContainer">
<form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="EmailAddressLoginField">Email Address:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="EmailAddressLoginField" id="EmailAddressLoginField"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="PasswordLoginField">Password:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="PasswordLoginField" id="PasswordLoginField"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="LoginButton" id="LoginButton" value="Login">
</form>
</div>
```

...see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868640/align-html-input-fields-by) question for other possibilities.

Comment: In modern web applications tables should only be used to display tabular data, certainly not for layout purposes.