# Aligning HTML Inputs

Tags: html, css

Im trying to align a number of inputs and select boxes within a single form.
ive tried various css styles to try to align them but everything seems to fail (??).

My html can be found here.

http://jsfiddle.net/felix001/kA8cd/3/

Does anyone known any easy methods for aligning these elements.

Thanks,

Comment: Align **how**? You need to be more specific. Do you want them in two columns, the inputs to all align to the left properly? Something else?

Comment: Need more info, but you need to have fixed widths on the labels and divs around the inputs, or simply put all of this in a table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align input forms in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309950/how-to-align-input-forms-in-html)

Comment: There is a large number of questions that effectively ask the very same thing, and you can find both the simple `table` method and various more complicated CSS ways in answers (search e.g. for “align input form”).

Comment: Sorry I should of been more clear Im looking for aligning all the inputs into a single column. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone known any easy methods for aligning these elements.

Yes, you can use Twitter Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

It offers fantastic, well written styles for common HTML elements (including forms). Use them as a starting point and expand from there.

Answer (score 0):

They used to say not to use tables for laying out non-tabular data, but in this case if you want a quick-and-dirty solution, it'd work. (Not that I'm condoning using tables for layouts; just putting it out there that it *is* an option should all else fail.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just align them label on left, input on right, you could try this:

> ​label { 
>       clear: both;
>       float: left;
>       min-height: 35px; } 
>   input, select { 
>       float: right; }​

It isn't the best solution, but if you're looking for something easy, quick and simple it should work. You may want to wrap everything in a div and set a width on that wrapper so that the fields and labels will be closer together as well.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use lists to line up my forms. I can't say whether this method still has wide adoption, but it's served me pretty well. I played around with your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/kA8cd/12/) to give you an example of how I lay out forms with lists, but I didn't fully style your example for you :)

Another list example http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/06/form-elements-design-using-css-and-list.html

Lists allow me to work with nice chunks. Like @Roddy said, tables will work, however a better option might be to layout your divs like a table with properties like `display: table-cell`.

You can also use floats like this guy http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/layout_form_without_tables_with_css_trick.aspx

I think all these methods work pretty decently. If you need a more specific answer, please provide details on how you would like to align your form.