# How align div to a form field?

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment, field

Currently I have the following HTML code.

```
            <div class="field">
            <label>E-mail address: </label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name='email' style="width:200px;"></input>
            <span class='warning' id="emailWarning" > </span>
            <div class="tip" id="emailTip"></div>

        </div>
```

However, I want the text in the div element (class = 'tip') to be aligned with the start of the form's text field. 
How should I do this using HTML and CSS?

Here's what is looks like now: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pEJMD/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/basillicum/pEJMD/1/) would be a quick workaround. You should put both the `.tip` div and the input into a wrapping div.

Comment: Thanks.. I ended up using this. 
I thought this would be a better approach than hard coding a value in pixels to 'shift' the 'tip' div to the right.. (as suggested in the other answers)

Answer (score 1):

Well, either you use a `<table>`, putting in one cell the `<label>` and in the other the `<input>`, or you use fixed widths/margins or paddings.

#### Solution 1: Table

<kbd>[**Table solution**](http://jsbin.com/ixetif/2)</kbd>

In this solution you use a table to hold the form. On column is for labels, the other column is for inputs. In this case you will have the tip in the input column, and it will align automatically with the input.

This has the **pro** to be working for flexible dimensions of your label/inputs. And **tables are not always evil**. Just remember that, if you want to keep your label aligned with the input, add a `vertical-align:top` to your CSS.

#### Solution 2: Fixed width

<kbd>[**Fixed-width solution**](http://jsbin.com/ixetif/1)</kbd>

In this solution you give a fixed width to your label, and move the `.tip` div using either `margin`, `padding` or `left`.

This will hold your layout in place, so be careful of extremely long labels!

Comment: Thanks.. that was a good answer. I prefer not to use tables because, according to w3schools, a tables are for displaying tabular data only. I'll stick with the other method. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a fixed size to the label. Than push the div to the right with the size of the label:

```
<div class="field">
   <label style="width:100px;">E-mail address: </label>
   <input type="text" id="email" name='email' style="width:200px;"></input>
   <span class='warning' id="emailWarning" > </span>
   <div class="tip" id="emailTip" style="margin-left:100px;">
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
   </div>
</div>
```

And the [result](http://jsfiddle.net/wh6zG/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an explicit width at all, nor tables; just use CSS tables (see my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23741073/695591)):

## CSS

```
form  { display: table;      }
p     { display: table-row;  }
label { display: table-cell; }
input { display: table-cell; }
```

## HTML

```
<form>
    <p>
        <label for="a">Short label:</label>
        <input id="a" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="b">Very very very long label:</label>
        <input id="b" type="text">
    </p>
</form>
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DaS39/1/

And if you need the labels right-aligned, just add `text-align: right` to the labels: http://jsfiddle.net/DaS39/

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-left`:

**Change:**

```
<div class="tip" id="emailTip">
```

**To:**

```
<div class="tip" id="emailTip" style="margin-left:95px;">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pEJMD/2/)

Learn more about the CSS `margin` property [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can give a `height` to the `label`, give a `width` to the parent `div` and `float` your `tip`. See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pEJMD/4/

Comment: Heh - I thought of this one too, but it's such a dirty, dirty hack =)

Comment: I guess the end justifies the means... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/4sJ2t/
You just need to give your label a fixed width, and then your tip a left margin

```
label {width:100px; text-align:right; margin-right:5px;}
.tip {margin-left:105px; padding: 5px 0;}
```