# Left align form labels, inputs also left aligned

Tags: css

So I'm trying to create a pretty form with labels. The aim is for all the labels to be inline with the inputs, while being left aligned. Because I also want to inputs to be left aligned, the space between each label and input is different.

[image: What I'm working with]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks as always, much obliged.

Comment: Could you post the code you currently have for that section?

Comment: Give fix width to labels

Comment: what Schleis said and here: http://jsfiddle.net/X68Xq/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align input forms in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309950/how-to-align-input-forms-in-html)

Comment: There is a large number of older questions about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the width of your labels to be the same and all your inputs will be aligned

```
label {
    display: inline-block; //So that we can set the width
    width: 40px; //Whatever the widest label will be.
}
```

This can cause some issues if you add longer labels, you may need to adjust the width so that it doesn't overflow.

Comment: The approach requires a guess on suitable width for the labels, and this is risky because you cannot know which font will actually be used. Using a table, as suggested in answers to earlier questions about this, is superior in this respect.

Comment: I agree having to know the correct widths is a drawback of this solution.   Using tables, IMO, is not a superior solution.  In the questions linked there are solutions to this problem that do not require wrapping the elements in a table.  These are a more superior solution to the problem.

Comment: The answer you are referring to does not contain any code, only a link, and the linked document (which happens to still exist) uses a fixed width setting for the label texts. And its not a matter of having to know the correct widths; how *could* you know them without making wild assumptions?

Comment: this is a great solution. Simple! Works.