# How to get two divs inline beside eachother?

Tags: html, css

Need help getting two divs to align beside each other, one contains 2 pictures, the other a video.

HTML

```
        <img src="example3.png" alt="CopeLogo" height="200" width="200" class="exlogo" >
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#pics{
text-align: center;
background-color: #194b6f;
height: 200px;
width: 500px;
float: left;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left: 50px;
border: 2px dashed black;}

#vid{
text-align: center;
background-color: #194b6f;
height: 490px;
width: 660px;
float: right;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 2px dashed black;
margin-right: 50px;}
```

Comment: I see your question. It is good, but can you please tell why your current code isn't working.

Comment: Please correct your code, most of the HTML cannot be seen.

Comment: Im sorry about the messy code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get your point but please do add your working codes to be more clear in your question.

You can actually do this:

HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="vid">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x150" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.vid {
  float: right;
}
.pic {
  float: left;
}
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa35a5zk/)

Comment: May I suggest adding `width: 50%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;` to `.vid` and `.pic`??

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

just use `float:left;` for both, also you can use `display:inline-block;` for both as well if you don't want to use `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: use DIVs to group each entity that you want to `float:left`.

You want to align the two images, so put each into a div, and float those divs left.

You want to align the box containing the two images with the box containing the video. Float each of those left.

When you use `float:left` (or right), the floated DIV is removed from the HTML "flow" and therefore has zero height. Therefore, the DIV containing a floated DIV (or other element) has zero height. Not good. To fix that, apply the clearfix hack to the parent div.

Here is a better explanation *(although it uses a different method to clear the floats -- both methods work fine):* [Customising Insightly HTML contact form (aligned, spaced fields)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367413/customising-insightly-html-contact-form-aligned-spaced-fields/36367690#36367690)

```css
/*  CSS:  */
body{min-width:650px;min-height:650px;}
#pics{float:left;border-radius:5px;XXXmargin-left:50px;border:2px dashed black;}
#picLeft {float:left;height:200px;width:200px;}
#picRight{float:left;height:200px;width:200px;}
#vid{float:left;height:200px;width:200px;border-radius: 5px;border:2px dashed black;}

.clearfix:after{content:"";clear:both;display:block;}
```

```html
<!--  HTML:  -->
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
  <div id="pics" class="clearfix">
    <div id="picLeft">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="MyLogo" height="200" width="200" class="mainlogo">
    </div>
    <div id="picRight">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/195/195" alt="CopeLogo" height="200" width="200" class="exlogo" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="vid">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8E8xMcXmI9E" width="195"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional References:

[CSS-Tricks: Clearfix hack](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

[Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699343/using-after-to-clear-floating-elements)

`Ahmed Alaa`'s answer also has a good tip: `display:inline-block` is also useful - +1

Answer (score 0):

`float` both elements `left` and adjust there widths accordingly.