# Issue with formatting in Internet Explorer (float)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, explorer

Having a bit of an issue with formatting on internet explorer

Site [here](http://www.myotechnology.com/)

In the header, all that stuff is supposed to appear in 1 row. In chrome and FF, it does, but when I open up ie9, it appears as a new line. I've tried changing the float, changing the display type and modifying the width and margin attributes but I can't get a fix on the issue.

For the headRight class, even when I change the width, it doesn't change in IE and I'm not sure why.

Code here:

```
.headRight { width:650px !important; _width:600px!important; float:right;}
.faderdiv
{
display:inline;
float:right;
margin-top: 35px !important;
}
.donate
{
display:inline;
float:left;
margin: 55px 90px 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: why does it move down on page load?

Answer (score 0):

this is actually for ie7 but I think this will work for your problems too. [IE7 float right problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820007/ie7-float-right-problems)