# ie7 with bootstrap CSS issue with div and positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

I have a problem positioning my title inside a div with grid classes (from bootstrap).
Here is my very simple code:

```
<body class=""  > 
 <div class="container " id="main">
  <div class="row " > 
   <div class="col-xs-3 " > 
   </div> <!-- /col-xs-3 -->
   <div class="col-xs-9 " >
    <h3 class="">Benvenuto</h3>
   </div> <!-- /col-xs-9 -->
   </div> <!-- /Row -->    
 </div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
```

There is no custom CSS added.

Here is my chrome output:
[image]
And here is my ie7 output:
[image]

As you con see using chrome the h3 si put **inside** the bootstrap div, while using ie7 is put **under** it.

[This](http://guglie.altervista.org/albatros_apartments/?id=1) is my test website, if you need to check it out.

Do you know how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: bootstrap doesn't support IE7. It is 8+. And IE7 is used by 0.3%. Why not supporting IE4? Are you ok? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820007/ie7-float-right-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As knitevision stated in his comment; IE 7 is not supported by Bootstrap.
IE 8 and 9 are partially supported.
(IE 8 needs responsive.js for responsive features to work)

But, there are some tricks to make it work if you absolutely need it, see this page: [Bootstrap 3 for IE7 (Beta)](http://www.extremecss.com/making-twitter-bootstrap-3-compatible-with-internet-explorer-7-and-below/). I haven't tested it on your page, but it might be worth a try!

See this page for for information on Bootstrap browser-support: [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support)